# TFS 2015 - Modify SQL Server Report (SSRS) to include column for listing check in files

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2008

We have one query used for pulling a report from SSRS. How can I add one more column to include the check in files too into it? For example in changeset id 123, I have checked in 2 files like `src/server/Abc.java` and `src/demo/Demo.java`. I would like to pull these two details in comma separated (concatenated) in the last column of the existing report.

Please see the existing report query. I am using Microsoft report builder for opening the rdl file.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Lines Modified], [Measures].[Code Churn Count], [Measures].[Lines Added], [Measures].[Lines Deleted] } ON COLUMNS
  , NON EMPTY { ([Version Control Changeset].[Changeset ID].[Changeset ID].ALLMEMBERS * [Version Control Changeset].[Changeset Title].[Changeset Title].ALLMEMBERS * [Version Control Changeset].[Checked In By].[Checked In By].ALLMEMBERS * [Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDateDate, CONSTRAINED) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToDateDate, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM (
    SELECT ( { [Team Project].[Project Path].&[\DefaultCollection\Ansar] } ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Code Churn])
  )
  WHERE ( [Team Project].[Project Path].&[\DefaultCollection\Ansar] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
    , FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```